# ¿Cuál es el mejor metodo para enviar un archivo desde el servidor al cliente? Con AspNET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post

estoy trabajando en una API construida en C# con MVC Asp Net 6
Estoy generando reportes en pdf a petición del cliente, y quiero enviarlos, en este caso el cliente es una aplicación en android que usa retrofit como cliente Http.

Para este caso los archivos que creara mi API en C# se generan de manera dinámica y solo estarán en el servidor por poco tiempo por lo cual no se si exponer el archivo como una ruta http sea lo más viable.

Hay alguna manera de hacerlo como un Output Stream o algo parecido?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar [FileResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.fileresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) de esta manera

```
    public async Task<FileResult> GetFoto(int id)
    {
        //byte[] fileBytes = 
        var ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes!);
        return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
        // o tambien:
        //return File(fileBytes, "application/pdf", "nombre.pdf");
    }
```